# Navigating a Python dictionary with nested values from ajax repsonse

Tags: python, ajax, json, dictionary, python-2.x

I'm trying to access some values that are nested as an ajax response from a website.

Everything is output as one giant line that I can't manage to navigate down. However to give you an idea of what it looks like, the pprint of the dictionary is something like:

```
    {u'd': {u'Type': None,
    u'__type': u'TOPS.ajaxResponse',
    u'actionOnSuccess': None,
    u'data': u'{"BasicCodes":{"PRODUCTPRICES":[{"ProductId":"ProductA","CategoryId":"1","Color":"Red","Quantity":"0"},{"ProductId":"ProductA","CategoryId":"2","Color":"Blue","Quantity":"0"},{"ProductId":"ProductB","CategoryId":"1","Color":"Red","Quantity":"0"},{"ProductId":"ProductB","CategoryId":"2","Color":"Blue","Quantity":"0"}, ...and so on...

    .
    .
    .

    u'data2': None,
    u'dataExtra': None,
    u'errors': [],
    u'general_message': None,
    u'success': True}}
```

There are hundreds of products listed (ProductA, ProductB, etc), but all I want to do is get the number associated with "Quantity" from a specific product like ProductB, Color Blue, for example.

I load the response as a dictionary by using

```
    json_data = urllib2.urlopen('website')
    content = json_data.read()
    dictionary = json.loads(content)
```

`dictionary.keys()` only outputs `'d'`, and `dictionary.values()` outputs EVERYTHING besides that, including things like `u'success': True`, which I would expect to be a separate key/value combo. If I try to navigate down the dictionary by using

```
    print dictionary['d']['data']['BasicCodes']['PRODUCTPRICES'][0]['Quantity']
```

I get an error of `TypeError: string indices must be integers`.

Is the problem how I am loading the data? Or am I missing something as I navigate the keys and values?

Not sure if it is related/relevant, but I also get an error `'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'` when I input

```
    dictionary['d']['data'].values()
```

I'm new to Python so any help would be appreciated on this.

Comment: The value of `dictionary['d']['data']` is clearly a string, not another dictionary: you can see that it is surrounded by `'`. You could decode that from JSON again, but sounds like you need to fix whatever is sending the data in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Because this kind of job is extremely hard in any language (not only in Python!) I created ObjectPath query language to make work with JSON documents a breeze:

**Python way:**

```
$ sudo pip install objectpath
$ python
>>> from objectpath import *
>>> with open('test1.json') as f:
...    j = json.load(f)
>>> tree=Tree(j)
>>> tree.execute("$..PRODUCTPRICES[@.ProductId is "ProductA" and @.Color is "Blue"].Quantity")
[u'0']
```

**Console way**

```
git clone https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath.git
cd ObjectPath/ObjectPathPy
python objectpath file.json
(or python objectpath -u URL)
>>> $..PRODUCTPRICES[@.ProductId is "ProductA" and @.Color is "Blue"].Quantity
[0]
```

You can do much much more with the language! It's like SQL for JSON (and other complex data structures). More at: http://adriank.github.io/ObjectPath/